# Representing schedules/time-table in relational data model

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a FX pricing system where we need to represent the set of ECNs/exchanges that are active at a given day of week + time of day.  So can represent the start time, end time and the ECN name that is active as a row.  The composite primary key will be start time + end time + the ECN.  E.g. -MTWThF- 08:00 London, -MTWThF- 14:30 New York, EBS.  Now there cannot be overlaps or duplicates.  People can edit the records and the constraints should hold.

How best to represent this at the database level?  If it helps we use Oracle, but a Oracle agnostic solution is preferred.

For now ignore time zones & daylight savings which make it impossible to avoid overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

I will give two answers, firstly, consider the repetition rule format from RFC 5545, and validating at the application layer.

Since that is probably not the answer you are looking for, I would also suggest looking at any point in the week as an offset from the start of the week.

You can then build a list of transitions which define the offsets into the week an exchange opens or closes.  The only constraint needed is to verify that the offset is valid (less than 7 days) and that an open to closed transition is only followed by a closed to open transition (and vice versa).

I do not have an oracle box open to play around in, but here is a sample in T-SQL:

```
create table #sched (exchangeID int, weekOffset int, isOpen bit)
insert into #sched 
values (1, 400, 1),
    (1, 800, 0),
    (1, 1200, 1),
    (1, 1700, 0);

-- constraints are that isOpen cannot be repeated.  1->0->1 is valid, 1->1->0 is not

declare @coffset int,
    @weekStart datetime;

set @weekstart = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0);
set @coffset = datediff(minute, @weekStart, getdate());

with trans (uniqid, exch, offset, isopen)
as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY weekoffset), *
    from (
        SELECT exchangeID, weekoffset - 7*24*60 as weekoffset, isopen from #sched
        UNION 
        select exchangeID, weekoffset, isopen from #sched
        UNION
        select exchangeID, weekoffset + 7*24*60, isopen from #sched
    ) as inr
)
select *,
    CASE pt.IsOpen 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Exchange is now open and will close at ' + CAST(DATEADD(minute, nt.offset, @weekstart) as varchar(20)) 
        ELSE 'Exchange is now closed and will open at ' + CAST(DATEADD(minute, nt.offset, @weekstart) as varchar(20)) END
from (
    SELECT MIN(uniqid) as nextTransition
    FROM trans
    WHERE offset > @coffset
) as n
cross join (
    SELECT MAX(uniqid) as prevTransition
    FROM trans
    WHERE offset <= @coffset
) as p
inner join trans as nt on nt.uniqid = nextTransition
inner join trans as pt on pt.uniqid = prevTransition

drop table #sched
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61b2f/3/0)** on sqlfiddle:

```
| NEXTTRANSITION | PREVTRANSITION | UNIQID | EXCH | OFFSET | ISOPEN |                                                   COLUMN_10 |
|----------------|----------------|--------|------|--------|--------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|              9 |              8 |      9 |    1 |  10480 |      1 | Exchange is now closed and will open at Feb 24 2014  6:40AM |
```